# Error code: 128 Error: aws codecommit needs to update to SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit

I am trying to run `eb create` but stuck on the step

```
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: aws codecommit credential-helper $@ get: aws: command not found
aws codecommit credential-helper $@ erase: aws: command not found
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/matrosovDev/parse-server-example/'
```

I've reinstall git with my homebrew on my Mac and removed all staff related to login via HTTPS and instead used SSH.

Looks like now this issue is gone.

one thing I didn't get that when I created environment via terminal command like it prompt me to create SSH for environment and it said that this key will be only for Region: eu-west-3

But I supposed I need to have SSH setup in my User in AWS which a little bit confuse me where is needed SSH setup is, in the User or in the environment.

I followed this article:

https://gist.github.com/hassy/48bae515c393e9214d3f